# Created dynamic grid with contents inside for a TabControl, how can I access them?

Tags: c#, wpf

on my mainwindow I created a TabControl.  then dynamically on load.. my program creates a grid.. then adds a bunch of objects (checkboxes, labels, etc) to the grid as such:

```
private Grid _grid;
scoresTabItem = new TabItem();
_grid.Children.Add(activeCheckBox);
_grid.Children.Add(scheduleScoresCheckBox);
_grid.Children.Add(team1NameLabel);
_grid.Children.Add(team1ScoreLabel);
scoresTabItem.Header = "Gm " + tabGameNum + ": " + homeTri + " vs " + awayTri;
scoresTabItem.Content = _grid;

window.ScoresTabControl.Items.Add(scoresTabItem);
window.ScoresTabControl.SelectedItem = scoresTabItem;
```

Now I want to be able to access the items on this dynamically created grid... but I have no idea how to do that.  The name of the TabControl on the mainwindow is "ScoresTabControl" i'm trying something like:

```
ScoresTabControl.Items..........
```

any help would be great

Comment: You are going to be fighting the WPF framework a lot doing it this way, consider making a Viewmodel and binding a collection of your "scoretabs" to the TabControl

Comment: Don't create or manipulate UI elements in procedural code in WPF. That's what XAML is for.

Answer (score 0):

there are few ways that you can try:

1- Use [RegisterName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.registername.aspx) method:

```
label lbl = new label();
lbl.Name = "ExampleLabel";

RegisterName("ExampleLabel", lbl);
```

then access it:

```
object j = this.FindName("ExampleLabel");
```

2- Use [VisualTreeHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.aspx) class to find object.